# How to use single player for both ads and video using google android Exoplayer

Tags: android, video, exoplayer

Currently in the given exoplayer demo app google is using two exoplayers to play ads and video. I have a problem of video overlapping while playing pre roll and mid roll ads. So to avoid this I want to use only one exoplayer to play both ads and video. Has anybody tried using single exoplayer?

Comment: I have resolved this issue. Please drop me a mail, I can share the code. I am at karthik.damodara88@gmail.com

Comment: Hi @Karthik can you send me the source code?I have done that using two exoplayers

Comment: Hi @JAPS  it depends how you want to use Exoplayer, Mine was a different case. Please drop me a mail and let me know your use case.

Comment: hey karthik i have mailed you can u please check it

Comment: @Karthikdamodara can you share me the code. My mail id rranjithkumar100@gmail.com

Comment: @karthik please share answer if you find it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just using MediaSource, use mediaSourceWithAds object:

```
MediaSource mediaSourceWithAds =
            new AdsMediaSource(mediaSource, dataSourceFactory, imaAdsLoader,
                    playerView.getOverlayFrameLayout(),null,null);
```

This should do it.

Comment: please tel me how to see in player timeline with ads?

Comment: do I terminate specific time for show ads? example start or midle of video?

Comment: that depends on your ad but it is mostly pre-roll, mid-roll and post-roll